# What would be the most effective data structure for storing and comparing directories in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, tree

So I am trying to develop an application in C# right now (for practice), a simple file synchronization desktop program where the user can choose a folder to monitor, then whenever a change occurs in said directory, it is copied to another directory.

I'm still in school and just finished my data structures course, so I'm still a bit of a new to this. But what I was currently thinking is the best solution would be a tree, right? Then I could use breadth-first search to compare, and if a node doesn't match then I would copy the node from the original tree to the duplicate tree. However that seems like it might be inefficient, because I would be searching the entire tree every time.

Possibly considering a linked list too. I really don't know where to go with this. What I've got accomplished so far is the directory monitoring, so I can save to a log file every time something is changed. So that's good. But I feel like this is the toughest part. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: What does "most effective" mean to you? Fastest, least memory, simplest data structure, smallest data structure, simplest code, most refactorable code, etc.

Comment: Something that I could reasonably be able to understand given I'm newer to data structures, and by efficient I mean the fastest.

Comment: Something reasonable to understand and something that is the fastest are likely to be two very different things. Why is speed important? So, for example, if option A takes 3ms and option B takes 10ms, do you care? If not, what do you mean by "fastest"?

Comment: I guess speed isn't that important then. What would would you recommend as a starting point?

Comment: I would just use two `List<FileInfo>` and compare the location, last write time, and file size to determine what to copy. File copying is slow compared to traversing a list in memory. I'd only worry about speed if you could show that processing power is slowing you down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash table (e.g., `Dictionary<string,FileInfo>`. One of the properties of a `FileInfo` is the absolute path to the file: use that as the key.

Hash table looks up are cheap (and fast).

Comment: Why use a redundant structure like this? If the `string` in the dictionary is the same as the `FullName` in the `FileInfo` it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There seems to be little value in the OP being able to do a fast look up. Afterall, if they have the string they can just do `new FileInfo(fileName)`.